# Rails ActiveStorage blob does not always load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, html5-video, rails-activestorage

I have a model that has `has_one_attached :example`. I have set everything up in views and controller to grab the blob.

`model_a` is the parent to `model_b` by `has_many`

`model_b has_one model_A, through: mode_c`

From controller:

```
@foo = current_program.model_a
    .includes(model_b: [model_A: [example_attachment: :blob]])
    .find(params[:id])
```

In view:

```
<% @foo.model_b.each do |set| %>
    <%= video_tag(url_for(set.model_A.example) %>
<% end %>
```

My question is some times the blob does not render/load, I look at the logs and I see there is no s3 call. However if I refresh the page or head to a different object that has the same blob it will render, sometimes. Again it's weird.

How do I debug this/ go about trying to figure this out. This happens on local and production. For production I use render.com.

Comment: have you checked whether it's being lazy loaded?

Comment: Are you referring to  the `302` redirect that comes with Active Storage attachments?

Comment: I guess I'm not sure what you mean by "sometimes the blob does not render/load"... I've had a similar issue where the attachment is a photo and it only loads when it's scrolled into view on the browser (lazy-loading).

Comment: Ah, ya that's not the case. Mine is the fact that the s3 call never happens, sometimes, when the Active storage Blob is queried.